# How to translate "Warts and all"

Tags: single-word-requests, translation, culture, meaning-in-context, idiom

**Warts and all** is an idiomatic English expression meaning *Including features or qualities that are not appealing or attractive*.

Edit Example:

> We trust that our partners will go on respecting and loving us, **warts
>   and all**.

I could translate that by the literal *veruko kaj ĉio* but I feel like I'm losing an opportunity to use or make an endemic Esperanta expression.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ĉu vi havas ekzemplan frazon?

Comment: Pardonu. "We trust that our partners will go on respecting and loving us, warts and all."

Answer (score 1):

In that English idiom you go explicitely for the "bad things", but you could take a more neutral approach, for example "the way we are" (it hints at good and bad things):

```
... respektas nin, tiaj kiaj ni estas.
```

Or, a bit more verbose, "with our good and bad sides":

```
... respektas nin, kun niaj bonaj kaj malbonaj flankoj (malbonaĵoj, plibonigeblaĵoj, ...)
```

If you want to keep the "bad things" as they are in the idiom, you could add *eĉ*:

```
.... respektas nin, eĉ kun niaj malbonaj flankoj.
```

Comment: Thank you very much !!